# Cannot initialize a variable of type 'double (*)[x]' with an rvalue of type 'double (*)[z]

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a vector of doubles that I am passing to a lib https://github.com/llohse/libnpy in order to read a numpy file:

```
std::vector<unsigned long> shape {};
bool fortran_order;
std::vector<double> dataNpy;

const std::string path {"/home/ubuntu/template.npy"};
npy::LoadArrayFromNumpy(path, shape, fortran_order, dataNpy);
```

I will need to further process this data and have been instructed to use arrays since vector copy is not optimal.

So this data should be a matrix but the lib reads it as linear.
That is why I want to create a pointer to a 2D table with a given size for rows and columns like this with the data from the vector

```
 double (*template_data)[12] = (double (*)[12]) dataNpy.data();
```

When I do it by explicitly putting the size, like above the compiler is ok with it, however, when I do it like the code below i get an error:

```
int sizeRows = 12, sizeColumns=12;
double (*template_data)[sizeRows] = (double (*)[sizeColumns]) dataNpy.data();
```

> `Cannot initialize a variable of type 'double ( * )[sizeRows]' with an rvalue of type 'double ( * )[sizeColumns]'`

Could you explain to me why that is?

Comment: First - why do you want to initialise arrays with (potentially) different lengths (`sizeRows` vs `sizeColumns`)? Second - variable length arrays are not standard C++ anyway

Comment: Not really clear what you are doing. But it looks like you want to say a linear piece of memory is actually a 2d array? Why not declare dataNpy as `std::array<std::array<double,12>,12>` (or `double dataNpy[12][12]`) in the first place?

Comment: Why not just treat the vector as a 2D array and access it directly? To access an entry at `x, y` you'd simply access `dataNpy[y * sizeColumns + x];`.

Comment: `double (*)[sizeColumns]` is not a type in C++

Comment: the size of an array must be a constant expression. `sizeRows` is not even `const`

Comment: @Caleth provided `sizeColumns` is a `constexpr`, it's a valid type in C++.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind from the code posted, it isnt

Comment: the message suggests that you are usign gcc which has variable length arrays as non-standard extension. Try `-pedantic-errors` to see whats "really wrong" in the code https://godbolt.org/z/Edvnvnvnv

Comment: `this data should be a matrix` - where does proportion of the matrix come from (num of columns vs num of rows)?

Comment: why not stay with the vector? `dataNpy[x + y*12]` is all you need to emulate 2d. If you like you can wrap the vector in a custom class to use something like `mat.at(x,y)` or similar

Comment: thank you, the const did the trick, i have edited the question to be more clear with what i am trying to achieve

Comment: even with the const you are using a rather fishy c-style cast. C-style casts are a red flag, because very often they hide bugs. If possible avoid them

Comment: the proportions come because i kind of know what to expect from that numpy file

Comment: @user3253067 so you anyway "hardcode" it and the row length is known at compile time?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind yes

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number to be honest i have been using this type of casting a couple of times, in order to pass from a 1D array to a 2D array, and i thought it could be doable in this case as well

Comment: *"like above the compiler is ok with it"* It is unfortunately UB too.

Comment: when something is not a 2d array you better do not pretend that it is one. Again, whats wrong with `dataNpy[x + y*12]` ?